# Determinant of this $N$ x $N$ matrix

Tags: determinant

Let $\nu$ be the minimum integer which satisfies $2\sin(\frac{\pi \nu}{2(N+1)})>\tau$, for $N$ an integer, and $\tau$ an arbitrary positive number. Since the LHS is bounded and RHS is not, there might be cases where no such value of $\nu$ satisfying the inequality does exist. In that case, we will take $\nu=0$. 
Now consider the polynomial:($a=\tau^2-2)$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\nu-1}ac_{i}^2-\sum_{i=\nu}^{N}ac_{i}^2+2\sum_{i=1}^{\nu-2}c_{i}c_{i+1}+2ic_{\nu}c_{\nu-1}-2\sum_{i=\nu}^{N}c_{i}c_{i+1}$$

Suppose I want to express the above as $c^{T}Ac$ with $c^{T}=\begin{matrix}
(c_{1} & c_{2} ... &c_{N})
\end{matrix}$

I want to calculate the NxN determinant of A:

$$   \begin{matrix}
    a & 1 & 0 & 0 .....&0 \\
    1 & a & 1 & 0.......&0 \\
    0 & 1 & a &1....... &0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 &a.....\\
.\\
.\\
0.\\\
\end{matrix}
$$
So we have repeating blocks of $\begin{matrix}
a & 1\\
1 & a\\
\end{matrix}$ until the $(\nu-2)^{th}$ row and similar repeating blocks of $\begin{matrix}
-a & -1\\
-1 & -a\\
\end{matrix}$ from the $(\nu+1)^{th}$ row and a block $\begin{matrix}
a & i\\
i & -a\\
\end{matrix}$ in the $(\nu-1)^{th}$ and $(\nu)^{th}$ rows. I could not write down the matrix here, so I would be obliged greatly if you check it yourself. As you can guess I am doing to this calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dc e^{-c^{T}Ac}$

Answer (score 0):

$$D_n=\begin{vmatrix}
a & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & a & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & a & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &\cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & a & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & a & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 1 & a\end{vmatrix}$$

$$D_1=a,\\D_2={{a}^{2}}-1,\\D_3={{a}^{3}}-2 a,\\D_4={{a}^{4}}-3 {{a}^{2}}+1,\\D_5={{a}^{5}}-4 {{a}^{3}}+3a,\\ \dots\\ D_n=aD_{n-1}-D_{n-2}$$
Determinants $D_n$ is  Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind:
$$D_n=U_n\left(\frac{a}2\right)$$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer but after there are blocks of $\begin{matrix}
-a & -1\\
-1 & -a\\
\end{matrix}$ after the $(\nu)^{th}$ row

Comment: Can you find the inverse of the matrix you calculated the determinant of? The adjoint calculation gets messy..is there a shorter way?